# android selected camera image through gallery intent is not displaying in imageview

Tags: java, android

//here is my gallery intent

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,2);



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           if (requestCode == 2) {
                Bitmap bm=null;
                if (data != null) {
                    try {
                        bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bm);
                File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
            } }
```

I am implementing camera and gallery intent in my android app.when i capture the through camera the image is displayed in imageview but if i try to display the same camera image through gallery intent the image is not displaying.

Note:captured image is not displaying through gallery intent but other folder images are displaying in imageview

Comment: There are many examples of this. You can check it proper and implement in your code

Comment: i tried examples then only i posted this question

Answer (score 2):

Bug #1: `ACTION_PICK` does not use a MIME type. Either use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` with a MIME type, or use `ACTION_PICK` with a collection `Uri` (e.g., `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`).

Bug #2: You are assuming that `MediaStore` knows how to get an image from that `Uri`. Since the `Uri` may not have come from the `MediaStore`, that is an incorrect assumption. Use Glide or Picasso to load the image into your `ImageView`.

Bug #3: You are loading the image on the main application thread. This will freeze your UI while the image is being loaded. Use Glide or Picasso to load the image into your `ImageView`, as they know how to do that work on a background thread.

Bug #4: You appear to have copied some code that "gets a `Uri` for a bitmap". You do not need to do that. You already have a `Uri` for the image. It is `data.getData()`, and you used it to try to load the image in the first place.

Bug #5: You appear to have copied some code that purports to get "a real path for a `Uri`". There is no reliable way of doing that. If you want a `File` that contains the data from the image, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`, then use that `InputStream` to copy the bytes to a `FileOutputStream` for some file that you control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below code, Hope it will help you.

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try {
   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   }

 imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: @Vishali you need to set FileProvider in AndroidManifest.xml file as well. Have you done it?

Comment: Go with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed